# Simulating an AJAX request from PHP script (Zend Framework 1.1x)

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, command-line-interface

In typical usage of this Zend/jQuery app, a user fills out a form, data is sent via an AJAX call and processed. I now have a need to trigger that processing from a script instead (in order to process a few hundred simulated forms at once).

So I have a

```
class FormsController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
   function ajaxAction() {
   *...process _POST here*
   }
}
```

The normal call looks something like this:

```
task=submit&id=form_103&data=formTarget%3Dparticipant%26targetID%3D1394%26name%3DTest%2BTester%26responseDate%3D2014-11-21%26ptcpDept%3D2&oldVersion=0
```

In my php cli script, I'm pulling data together from a different source, formatting it to look like the contents of _POST above, and essentially what I want to do is call the action. But I don't know how to access it. I have a CLI bootstrap that allows me to instantiate Models and access the database, etc:

```
/ Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap();
```

but I can't instantiate a Controller through the script, which was my hunch:

```
   $formsC = new FormsController;
```

returns a fatal error (Class not found).

Thanks in advance!